# How can I make a PDF file using base64 string ? Swift

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, swift2, base64

I'm looking for a way to save a PDF file on my project directory, I've received a base 64 pdf string from a Web Service yet. Do I have to convert it to NSData or something like that?

I'm new at coding in Swift but I can follow your instructions.

I hope you can help me. Thanks

Comment: Decode the base 64 string into Data, then save the data

Comment: Update your question with some relevant code. Show what you have so far with regard to the PDF data. Also explain what you have attempted.

Answer (score 27):

Yes, you have to convert it to Data and then save it to the documents directory on the device. A function like this would work:

```
func saveBase64StringToPDF(_ base64String: String) {

    guard
        var documentsURL = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last,
        let convertedData = Data(base64Encoded: base64String)
        else {
        //handle error when getting documents URL
        return
    }

    //name your file however you prefer
    documentsURL.appendPathComponent("yourFileName.pdf")

    do {
        try convertedData.write(to: documentsURL)
    } catch {
        //handle write error here
    }

    //if you want to get a quick output of where your 
    //file was saved from the simulator on your machine
    //just print the documentsURL and go there in Finder
    print(documentsURL)
}
```

Comment: this is working. I tried in swift 3.0

Comment: how can we open the pdf from the app?

Comment: how to display this PDF file later, from document directory in PDFView

Answer (score 0):

You want something like:

```
if let d = Data(base64Encoded: base64string) {
    do {
        try d.write(to: outputFile)
    } catch {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

Where `base64string` is the base64 PDF string, and `outputFile` is a URL for the PDF output file.

Comment: Don't use `try!`. Do actual, proper error handling.

Comment: Sorry They gave me this project on Swift 2.0, what's que equivalent?