# How to convert String to PDF in Swift

Tags: pdf

Can you tell me how to convert this string to PDF...

%PDF-1.3%âãÏÓ2 0 obj<>streams8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W&tp](9o5Q:]`!!<3$!!#7!!!!'"p](9o&,lP/!!`K(!!#4`!!!'"p](9o#P\9!!!`K(!!#1_!!!'"p](9o"8Dir!!`K(!!#1_!!!'"p](9o"7Q9j!!<3$!!#+]!!!'"p](9o!T3qX!!<3$!!"tY!!!'"p^dE(!T5("s8N3$s8Vj!s8W-!p`KP9J`&cms8N3$s8Vj)s8W-!p`KP9J`&cms8N3$s8Vj9s8W-!p`KP9J`&cms8N3$s8Vj)s8W-!p`KP9!T63Bs8N3$s8Vj)s8W-!p](9o!T3qX"9/?$!!Dur!!*'!p](9o!Up'h!.OtK!!E-!!!",@p](9o"7Q9j!'^G`!!E-!!!!Q0p](9o"8Dir!$;1@!!E3#!!!9(p](9o"8i-!!"T&0!!E6$!!!-$p](9o!WE'!!!`K(!!E7O!!!-$p](9o!WTq8!!`K(!!E8j!!!'"p^dE)!<<*!r!*?(s8W-!s8N-"p`KP9JH,ZLrW`Q*s8W-!s8RZMp`KP9JH,ZLrW`Q*s8W-!s8RZMp`KP9JH,ZLr!*?(s8W-!s8N-"p`KP9!<<*!r!*?(s8W-!s8E'!p](9o!8mhW!!`K(!!"tY!!!'"p](9o!T3qX!"T&0!!"tY!!!-$p](9o!T3qX!"T&0!!"tY!!!-$p](9o"5j.Z!$;1@!!"tY!!!9(p](9o#N,R^!'^G`!!"tY!!!Q0p](9o&)[Ef!<3$!!!"tY!!#7`p](9oJ,fQKs8W-!s8Vurs8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!s8W-!

Comment: I guess this already _is_ a pdf.

Comment: yes But how to write on Document path

Comment: If you actually have those data in a string object, they most likely already are broken beyond repair. Pdf is a binary format, and putting arbitrary binary data into a string, i.e. decoding them according to some assumed character encoding, usually maps Sequences of bytes without meaning in that encoding to some character like '?' and so loses information.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete pdf file, your missing %%EOF, and there can be multiple %%EOF in a single PDF.  Your also missing the end of the object and the end of the stream as well.  Assuming you had the complete pdf file as a string, you would have to know what encoding was used to get that string, and use the same encoding to write it back to a binary(hex) file.

**This is a duplicate of:**  [How can I make a PDF file using base64 string ? Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163277/how-can-i-make-a-pdf-file-using-base64-string-swift)

Comment: Thanks for response Jeff Luyet that string part of PDF String because we are converting first base64 then convert to data that data write to path open file showing invalid PDF. plz can you suggest how to convert??

Comment: I would convert the base64 to hex, then write the hex to file.  Do you prefer any specific language or just any language?

Comment: for swift do you have any idea? how to convert

Comment: I'm in a windows environment today, If I was in my linux environment Ide definately give it a shot.  After doing a little bit of googling, this looks like what you need:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163277/how-can-i-make-a-pdf-file-using-base64-string-swift

Answer (score 1):

This is a complete sample how to store, get and share a base64 encoded PDF 
I hope it will be usefull.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBAction func sharePDFActionButton(_ sender: Any) {
    do {
        try savePdf()
        loadPDFAndShare()
    } catch  {
        print("FALLO EL GUARDAR EL PDF")
    }

}

let pdfString = "PUT ANY BASE64 ENCODED PDF FILE"
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

func savePdf() throws {
    let documentsURL = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
    let pdfDocURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("document.pdf")
    let pdfData = Data(base64Encoded: pdfString)
    try pdfData!.write(to: pdfDocURL)
}

func loadPDFAndShare(){
    do {
        let documentsURL = try FileManager.default.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
        let pdfDocURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent("document.pdf")

        let document = NSData(contentsOf: pdfDocURL)
        let activityViewController: UIActivityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: [document!], applicationActivities: nil)
        activityViewController.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView=self.view
        present(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        print("document was not found")
    } catch  {
        print("document was not found")
    }
  }
}
```

Best regards.