# How to download pdf file coming from server which is in base64string?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I need to download pdf file which I get in api response as a base64string.

How should I save it locally based on cell tag and preview it using documentcontroller?

Eg-api response is an array of dictionaries with different pdf files where we have a key called "pdf":"zcvffaewww.."

I need to download these pdf files on tap of uibutton on uitableviewcell and preview it in documentcontroller.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: refer this link
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40163277/how-can-i-make-a-pdf-file-using-base64-string-swift

Answer (score 1):

you are getting a base64 string in JSON, it means you are getting the file name and file type also right (if not getting then it is fine)

**Step 1**: Instead of download, you can view that PDF in webView. Here is the way to do this,

```
// convert your base64 string into NSData
NSData* myData = [NSData dataFromBase64String: yourBase64String];
```

then write below code to show pdf in webView,

```
[_webView loadData:myData
                 MIMEType:@"application/pdf"
                 textEncodingName:@"NSUTF8StringEncoding"
                   baseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.google.co.in/"]];

// zooming pdf view

 _webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;
 _webView.autoresizingMask = (UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight);
```

It will show pdf in webView

**step 2**: for downloading pdf, write code

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:
                      [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:application/pdf;base64,%@",
                       numStr]];

NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
if ( urlData )
{
  NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
  NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];  

  NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"filename.pdf"];
  [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}
```